# How can I boot into recovery mode if it hangs booting single user?

Tags: 11.10, boot, upstart

How can I boot into recovery mode if it hangs booting into single user mode?

I am trying to boot into "recovery mode" or any single user mode, but upstart is trying to start modem-manager no matter what. It says "modem-manager could not connect to system bus" and sits there retrying, forever.

Can I boot into single user mode and tell upstart to NOT try starting the modem?

Can I boot single user and tell upstart to start a shell after drives are mounted? Thanks for any help in advance...

UPDATE: I was able to use the grub init=/bin/bash trick to get a command prompt on booting. From there I was able to apt-get purge modemmanager. But I still get an error about can't connect to system bus and a hang. Is there a way to put upstart into extra verbose mode so I can see what is causing the hang?

Comment: When you boot, remove the "quiet" from the boot options. When you get a shell, check the logs. If it will not boot at all, we can investigate from a live CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of Googling the different terms, I found a post that may solve your problem also.

For me that was a bug for Ubuntu 11.10. Take a look at this [post](http://uksysadmin.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/upgrade-to-ubuntu-11-10-problem-waiting-for-network-configuration-then-black-screen-solution/) for solution.
And to repeat the solution here:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> at the blank screen to get you to a non-X terminal (tty1)
2. Login in with your username and password
3. Change to root with: `sudo -i` and enter your password
4. `mkdir -p /run /run/lock`
5. `rm -rf /var/run /var/lock`
6. `ln -s /run /var`
7. `ln -s /run/lock /var`
8. Reboot

Comment: TY!  I had no idea /var/run and moved to /run and is symlinked and same goes for /var/lock and both are tmpfs.  I googled a ton and never saw this blog post nor any detail that they are tmpfs.

Answer (score 1):

"Could not connect to the system bus" means dbus. Without dbus, you probably can't boot. I think you need to figure out why dbus isn't starting.

Are you using a standard kernel?

Comment: yes, you are right, no dbus. yes standard kernel. when I init=/bin/sh and try service start, it says dbus is already running. I guess because /var/run/dbus/pid is there because of unclean shutdown.